# Colon with column name in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a seen a mysql code that looks like this

```
select * from customer
where name = :name;
```

In `Mysql` using colons in front of the value is not permitted, my assumption is the query is provided with a colon to bind it with `PHP` functions.

What I am looking for is which function is used to bind the queries with colons?

So far I have checked `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` but mechanism used to replace parameter with value is question mark and not colon.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Go through this page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and you will learn about those prepared statements. What you are seeing is a prepared statement and not the final query that will be executed. By the time its sent to mysql for execution that colon will be gone and there will be a value for `name`

Comment: are you using mysqli or mysql? big difference in queries between the two, and like Hanky lanky said, you are probably confusing the two. mysqli and PDO (which you may have also seen use question marks to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct with the binding, but there are two ways;

- `?` - a simple placeholder, which you would bind with numerical indexes. For example;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`,`baz`) VALUES (?, ?)";
$smt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$smt->bindParam(1, $bar);
$smt->bindParam(2, $baz);
// ...
```

- `:foo` - a simple placeholder, which you would bind with a string index. For example;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`,`baz`) VALUES (:bar, :baz)";
$smt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$smt->bindParam(':bar', $bar);
$smt->bindParam(':baz', $baz);
// ...
```

There are two database APIs available that involve binding;

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

You can see [this article by "Use the Index, Luke"](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters) to see how binding is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taken from php.net:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

You should try searching on Google before asking here as this is simple function call.

For more details, please check: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php